# Static polymorphism with forwarding references

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, static-polymorphism

I am trying to use static polymorphism like in the simple example shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    decltype(auto) foo() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).foo(); }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Traits;

template <typename T>
struct Traits<Base<T>>
{
    using Derived = T;
};


template <typename T>
struct Object
{
    template <typename U>
    Object(U&& data) : m_data(std::forward<U>(data)) {}

    T m_data;
};

template <typename T>
decltype(auto) polymorphicCall(T&& obj)
{
    using Derived = typename Traits<std::decay_t<T>>::Derived; 
    return Object<Derived>(static_cast<Derived&>(obj));
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    polymorphicCall(d);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that `T` in `polymorphicCall` is deduced as `Derived`, this way anything can be passed to that function, even `int`. Is there a way to only accept `Base<Derived>` types?

I tried using a forwarding reference and an `enable_if` on the template parameter, but then i can't deduce the `Base`s template parameter.

Is there any way to use both forwarding references and static polymorphism?

EDIT: Updated the code example to include the actual forwarding reference and how a try to use it.

The error shown is: "error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Traits'"

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/3EcS47

Comment: I still find this confusing. In `polymorphicCall` you already have `T` deduced as `Derived&`. You then introduce a type alias `Derived` which would get the type `Derived`?

Comment: Also note that `T` in `Object` is not a forwarding reference, it's an rvalue reference.

Comment: @super And i know i have `T` being deduced as `Derived`, but that is the problem.
This way anything can bededuced and accepted by the function. I only want to accept `Base<Derived>` types

Comment: If that's all you want to achieve, you just need to improve you type trait and add a `static_assert`

Comment: @super I've tried `static_assert`, but for some reason the `Trait` just won;t recognise that `T` even if it is deduced as `Derived` in polymorphicCall, can be viewed as a `Base<Derived>` and it does not choose the right specialization

Comment: You can't change `Derived` to `Base<Derived>` the inheritance is only by pointer or references. The argument will always be of type derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is just to limit the use of `polymorphicCall` to types derived from `Base` you can do that with a `static_assert` and a type trait.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    decltype(auto) foo() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).foo(); }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct IsDerivedFromBase : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct IsDerivedFromBase<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base<T>, T>>> : std::true_type {};


template <typename T>
struct Object
{
    template <typename U>
    Object(U&& data) : m_data(std::forward<U>(data)) {}

    T m_data;
};

template <typename T>
decltype(auto) polymorphicCall(T&& obj)
{
    using Derived = std::remove_cvref_t<T>;
    static_assert(IsDerivedFromBase<Derived>::value);
    return Object<Derived>(std::forward<T>(obj));
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    polymorphicCall(d);
    int i;
    //polymorphicCall(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where in the example you need to know the `Derived` type, but you can make type traits that will give you `Derived` for each `Base` instantiation:

```
template <typename>
struct derived_of;

template <typename Derived>
struct derived_of<Base<Derived>>
{
    using type = Derived;
};
```

and use it with decayed types.

Comment: Tried this, it won't work with forwarding references. And i also did it with `std::remove_reference`.

Comment: @PetokLorand Could you link a MCVE, please?

Comment: I updated the question to include a more complete code example